# JavaMail, Exchange Server and “no login methods supported”

Tags: authentication, exchange-server, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm trying to read contents of a mailbox, using JavaMail and IMAP.
No SSL, only plain IMAP.

My code is like this:

```
    // Connection default properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.timeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.timeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.connectiontimeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.timeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "5000");

    // Get session
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(true);

    // Get the store
    Store store = session.getStore(account.getProtocol()); // returns "imap"
    String username = account.getUsername();
    String password = account.getPassword();
    String host = account.getHost();
    store.connect(host, username, password);

    // Get folder
    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
    Message messages[] = folder.search(ft);
    System.out.println("Ci sono " + messages.length + " messaggi da leggere");
```

Here is what i get:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbqh7gt3xqgobo7/imap_error.png

It seems that Exchange server is rejecting my login trials...i'm stuck with this and can't understand how to proceed further.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

The server is configured not to allow 'LOGIN' on plaintext ports.

Note the CAPABILITY response: `LOGINDISABLED`, and no alternative AUTH methods are presented.  You will likely need to connect with SSL encryption.

On the other hand, I don't know why they'd keep open the plaintext port if it can't be used....

Comment: They probably want you to use STARTTLS to switch the connection to SSL/TLS.  Set the property "mail.imap.starttls.enable" to "true".

Comment: StartTLS isn't shown in the capability list so a client will not attempt it.

Comment: Ya, you're right, he probably needs to connect with SSL to begin with.  Set the property "mail.imap.ssl.enable" to "true".  Might also need to set "mail.imap.ssl.trust" to the server host name or to "*".

Comment: Thank you. In the end I called Exchange server's admins. 
I let them notice that server was clearly not configured to permit AUTH/PLAIN login...
They did some changes in configuration, and since that all is working properly, now.